# Can I search my cwd for a number of files one by one?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, file-search

I am trying to search my cwd to see if a number of files exist one by one. I am trying to write a loop whereby it searched the directory for file #1, prints a true or false and then searches for file #2

This is my first attempt at coding such a function and I do not know where to start

Comment: Hi Sam, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please tell us more about what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have used os.path.exists and os.path.isfile for individual searches, but I am looking to search for 10 files one after the other

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this

```
from pathlib import Path
file_list = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]
for f in file_list:
    print Path(f).is_file()
```

This code will loop through the files in the list file_list and print out a true/false for whether they exist or no.